# WP7 Binding Image control to an image URI that needs cookie

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, xaml, webclient

I am developing an app that consumes RESTful web services that needs login. This login is verified with session cookies and to download any data with a `WebClient`, I have used the following extension:

```
public class CookieWebClient : WebClient
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public CookieWebClient() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = App.GlobalCookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

However, some of the data returned is URIs for image thumbnails that are shown in different `ListBoxes`. Before I had to use login for the web services, I simply just bound the `ImageSource` to the specified URI in the data:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Icon_Url}" />
```

However, now that I have to use login, I have to provide a cookie when fetching the image. I thus thought that an `IValueConverter` would do the trick, where I would pass in the URI, which would then download the `BitmapImage` with my extended `WebClient`, right until I remebered that I can only do asynchronous calls with `WebClient` on WP7.

### So my question is

How do I download images for a `Image` controls in a `LisBoxItem` that has to have a cookie in the request?

Thank you!

Comment: why is async call stopping you from using WebClient?

Comment: @igrali I think it is preventing him from using it in an `IValueConverter`, not in general.

Comment: @Nate oh I see, OK... I guess he should not use the IValueConverter then? :-)

Comment: There may be a better way, but you could try to cache them in Isolated Storage and bind from there.

Comment: @Nate We recently had a visit from a Microsoft WP developer at my company, who talked a lot about images in WP7. It turns out that the hanlding of images is extremely poor memory wise, which is why I want the built in controls to handle images as much as possible in order not to have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image with the http classes and set the image manually:

```
var stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream(); 
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(stream);
image.Source = bitmap;
```

But this will not work with simple XAML bindings... (but you can wrap this logic in an attached property)